# Problems reviewing such wide ranging topics

Tags: discussion

I've recently forced myself to be more active with review tasks, and I've also run into a big problem with review tasks that is also a bit related to something that might be a problem with SF overall.

Much of the content to be reviewed is clearly bad or clearly good, but as much as half of it is a lot more subtle. And frankly, I don't understand a lot of the content on SF, including content that I'm reviewing.

I'm a Microsoft-focused professional. I know an awful lot about the Microsoft ecosystem, from licensing to cloud services and most of the things in between. I know hardly anything about Unix flavors and their descendants, nginx, Docker, F5s, Apache, OpenSSH, etc.

When looking at the question list in general, it's not a big deal since I can just highlight my favorite tags and filter my least favorite. But when reviewing, I find myself selecting "Skip" on maybe 1/3 of my review tasks.

Is that a problem? Is that what the "Skip" button is there for?

Comment: There is a skip button - use it.

Comment: @user430214 Hmm.. didn't read my entire question, I'm guessing?

Comment: I agree with other, I skip a lot! as myselft iam focussed Microsoft also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't sweat it. If you don't feel you can do a question/answer justice for whatever reason, pressing "Skip" is the appropriate action.

Citing https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues

> If you're unsure about the post, use the "Skip" button to move on to the next review item without taking action on the current one.

That's one more thing why the review system is broken - it should only show you posts with tags relevant for you to not waste your time.

Comment: I wonder if this is really a review problem or an opportunity to further spin off site(s) from SF. Yes, there is overlap between LAMP and Microsoft, but I'm starting to think a separate Microsoft servers and services focused stack may be justified. Assuming it hasn't already been proposed and declined in Area 51 (which it probably has). Anyway, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: I don't believe SE would want to go there. SO is massive and could be split into at least half a dozen sub sites, but they still keep this behemoth going. With SF, personally I wouldn't want this to happen because I've learned a lot just by browsing questions about things I don't know much about and I would most likely not go over to MS related site on a regular basis.

Comment: Good points. That said, I note the existing of both a Unix/Linux stack and a dedicated Ubuntu stack. Another point against a separate Microsoft stack is that there really doesn't seem to be as much Microsoft traffic on SF, by a wide margin. If a Microsoft stack magically appeared overnight, it might never make it out of beta for lack of sufficient interest separate from SF, unlike the Unix/Linux and Ubuntu stacks.

Comment: UL and AskUbuntu exist for "user" questions.  SF is a professionally-focused site.  And yes, the "skip" button is your friend (I hammer it regularly).

Comment: @ToddWilcox I doubth too that another stack can be useful, as the lack of questions about MS product is not because SF dont serve them well, its because MS direct new user to the technet forum first. (Kinda why Iam happy on SF, lot less entry level questions here usually)

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Windows, and won't use it (or any other proprietary software) for anything.  I end up pressing skip about a third of the time, too.

I don't think you should sweat it.  You know what you know about, and you're happy to rule on those sort of questions.  You know what you don't know about, and you're happy to leave those alone.  Good for you, I say.  (And there's nothing wrong with Sevn's answer, which I have upvoted - I merely add this so you know that others use skip with comparable frequency.)